# Popen Command Prompt weird behaviour

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I was fiddling with the `subprocess.Popen` and got to a weird situation I just can't explain. Leaving here in the hope someone can make some sense of this.

## Description

Spawning a `cmd.exe` subprocess from the python process, results in the prompt switching from python to cmd. And when the python prompt is shown the command is executed in `cmd.exe`. On the other hand when the `cmd.exe` prompt is shown, issuing a command executes in the python shell.

Getting to this weird back and forth prompt. An example as follows:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Pedro Rodrigues>help
Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.
>>>
```

Apparently a Windows Command Prompt. But, not only the `help` command is python's, afterwards we appear to be dropped in the python shell.

But, if we do it again. Its actually the other way around. This is now the Windows Command Prompt, but we are presented with the python prompt!

```
>>> help
For more information on a specific command, type HELP command-name
ASSOC          Displays or modifies file extension associations.
... supressed ...
WMIC           Displays WMI information inside interactive command shell.

For more information on tools see the command-line reference in the online help.

C:\Users\Pedro Rodrigues>
```

And this keeps on going, the terminal is essentially useless at this point, as far as I could tell.

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Open a python shell, either:

   - Open Command Prompt, and type `python`.
   - Open a python shell.
2. Run the following code:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')
```

1. Type `help`, press `ENTER`.
2. Repeat previous step.

## What is going on?

I'm surprised by the result. With that said, I just cannot explain what is happening here.

## On Linux

The behaviour is a bit different, although it also renders the terminal useless. I haven't played a lot with it on Linux, but did various times end up with a working terminal actually.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash')
```

But most of the times, got a working bash shell. Which stopped the python process every time.

*I understand this is an esoteric scenario, yet what happens on Windows puzzles me.*

Comment: Since you didn't specify new STDIN, STDOUT, or STDERR channels for your subprocess, they are shared with that of the parent Python process.  I believe it's mainly a matter of luck as to which of the two are going to receive any given line of input.  If Python happened to get a particular line, it's going to display the resulting output, and then issue a new prompt - but that doesn't mean it's any more likely to get the next line you type than cmd.exe is.

Comment: @jasonharper Can you post as an answer?